# Decleare and initialize object in Java - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, object

I am starting to work with Android Studio, and therefore with Java and I am a bit lost. I have created a simple `User.java` where I create the structure of my User. Nevertheless, when trying to add a new `Object` to my `class` I am not able to do it.

I want to set an object. As simple as that :)

**User.java**

```
public void setProgress() {
    this.progress = new Object({
            accomplishedToday = true,
            completedGoals = 0,
            daysInRow = 0,
            unlockedBadges = null
    });
}
```

}

What I am trying to achieve is to create an object like the one shown below when initializing a User (`new User()`) but I am missing the attribute `progress`

[image]

Is there any way to do it without creating another external `class`?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create Progress class to achieve what you want.

And since you are just starting, maybe should switch to Kotlin. It'll save you from creating all these getters and setters just by using `data class`

Comment: Is not possible to create it without a new data class? Just like in Javascript object = {}

Comment: @Mario As far as I know - no it's not possible to do so.